# Problem with Basic Diffuse Lighting

Tags: texture, c++, brdf, directx11, diffuse

So recently I have been learning how to implement Diffuse Lighting in DirectX and I have done so with the following code:

```
float4 PS(VS_OUTPUT input) : SV_TARGET
{
    input.normal = normalize(input.normal);

    float4 diffuse = ObjTexture.Sample(ObjSamplerState, input.TexCoord);

    float3 finalColor;

    finalColor = diffuse * light.ambient;
    finalColor += saturate(dot(light.dir, input.normal) * light.diffuse * diffuse);

    return float4(finalColor, diffuse.a);
}
```

which has produced the following results:

[image]

Before I progress any further with specular lighting I wanted to clean up my code a little so I re-implemented this with a function and few changes.

```
float3 DirectDiffuseBRDF(float3 diffuseAlbedo, float nDotL)
{
    return (diffuseAlbedo * nDotL);
}

float4 PS(VS_OUTPUT input) : SV_TARGET
{
    input.normal = normalize(input.normal);

    float4 diffuseAlbedo = ObjTexture.Sample(ObjSamplerState, input.TexCoord);

    float nDotL = saturate(dot(input.normal, light.dir));

    float3 diffuseLighting = DirectDiffuseBRDF(diffuseAlbedo, nDotL);

    return float4(diffuseLighting, diffuseAlbedo.a);
}
```

Which produces:

[image]

As you can see the modified code has it's diffuse lighting a little different compared to the original. What am I missing from the original code to get it back to normal?

Answer (score 3):

Your ambient lighting contribution is missing from the second one (:

Answer (score 1):

```
float3 DirectDiffuseBRDF(float3 diffuseAlbedo, float nDotL)
{
    return (diffuseAlbedo * nDotL);
}

float4 PS(VS_OUTPUT input) : SV_TARGET
{
    input.normal = normalize(input.normal);

    float4 diffuseAlbedo = ObjTexture.Sample(ObjSamplerState, input.TexCoord);

    float nDotL = dot(input.normal, light.dir);

    float3 diffuseLighting = diffuseAlbedo * light.ambient * light.diffuse;

    diffuseLighting += saturate(DirectDiffuseBRDF(diffuseAlbedo, nDotL);

    return float4(diffuseLighting, diffuseAlbedo.a);
}
```

This seemed to have fixed it. I was forgetting to multiply my Ambient light.

Comment: And what about light.diffuse (diffuse light color?)

Comment: Oh I forgot to add in that, I've updated my answer with it.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `color = diffuse + ambient` ?

Comment: Yeah, you should not be multiply ambient, if it is 0 you will end up with 0 diffuse. It should be diffuse + ambient